# QNAP NAS nohup: no such file or directory

Tags: java, nohup, nas

I try to run a jar file from shell on my qnap nas and tried to use nohup:

```
nohup java extender.jar &
```

But i get an error

```
nohup: no such file or directory
```

if i run

```
java extender.jar
```

it works.

i tried to find nohup

```
find -name nohup
```

but the result is empty. It seems to me nohup is not installed. But how can i install nohup? Sorry for this question but i am new to linux.

Comment: . nohup java -jar extender.jar  &       (note dot space in front)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nohup is not installed on a QNAP NAS!

You can install it:

1. Install ipkg from Webinterface Application Manager (QPKG)
2. Login via ssh and run:
3. ipkg update
4. ipkg list | grep coreutils
5. ipkg install coreutils

Thats all!

Comment: I tried on mine and there's no ipkg available to install.